# AD User randomly can't access network resources

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

I have a user running a Windows 10 Enterprise (1709) x64 laptop on our Active Directory domain. She is connected inside the corporate network via wired Ethernet. (have tried wifi, the same happens)

She has been complaining about an odd issue, whereby every-so-often when she tries to access a network resource such as the intranet (which is LDAP based authentication) or a mapped network drive, she cant, almost as if her AD account has been locked.
She logs off and on again, and hey-presto, it's working again.

Just to add, when this happens, her phone also complains that it can't connect to the email server. 
Sop this sounds like some sort of account lock within AD but nobody is going in to unlock it - it unlocks itself.

Edited to add: 
I've just checked on the user account in AD, and it says she is currently locked out!

[image]

It seems to lock and unlock itself with no admin intervention.

2 minutes later...

[image]

Comment: Maybe one of her email clients has the wrong password stored, and is triggering the temporary lockout? Does the AD server have failed-login logs?

Comment: I ahven't got time at the minute to write this one up but this link has a cracking method to identify a root cause of a frequent accont lockout: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/48758-trace-the-source-of-a-bad-password-and-account-lockout-in-ad. I work for a University where staff have email and eduroam on their personal devices and something so simple as chagning their password causes a knock-on effect because they forget where they have signed in and not updated the password.

Comment: That's actually a really useful article - Thanks you, bookmarked. 
I've figured it out now, it seems that native windows10 mail app was working in the background, no prompts, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the user had managed to set up the Windows 10 Mail app by mistake, (we run Exchange and Outlook) and despite it not running, it was still active as a background app even after multiple restarts.

we gave this her new password and now its happy.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer.